# Unable to Fetching data from MongoDB in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to fetch emails data based on current logged-in user and using token for user authentication, i am getting now errors but got empty response.

Below is my backend API

```
app.get('/api/emails/inbox', async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1];
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
    }
  
    try {
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      const userEmail = decodedToken.email;
  
      // Fetch inbox emails from the database where the user's email is in the "to" field
      const inboxEmails = await Email.find({ to: userEmail });
  
      // Map the email objects to include only the necessary fields
      const formattedEmails = inboxEmails.map(email => ({
        id: email._id,
        from: email.from,
        to: email.to,
        subject: email.subject,
        body: email.body,
        timestamp: email.timestamp,
      }));
  
      res.json(formattedEmails);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error verifying token or fetching emails:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
  });
```

Here is my frontend code block that fetches emails data from the db using API defined in the previous code block;

```
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("Current Folder: ", currentFolder);
      fetchEmails(currentFolder);
      const userName = loggedInUserEmail || "User";
      switch (currentFolder) {
        case 'inbox':
          document.title = `Inbox - ${userName}`;
          break;
        case 'sent':
          document.title = `Sent Items - ${userName}`;
          break;
        case 'drafts':
          document.title = `Drafts - ${userName}`;
          break;
        case 'deleted':
          document.title = `Trash - ${userName}`;
          break;
        default:
          document.title = `Email - ${userName}`;
          break;
      }
    }, [currentFolder, loggedInUserEmail]);
    
    const fetchEmails = async (currentFolder) => {
      let url;
      switch (currentFolder) {
        case 'inbox':
          url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/emails/inbox';
          break;
        case 'sent':
          url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/emails/sent';
          break;
        case 'drafts':
          url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/emails/drafts';
          break;
        case 'deleted':
          url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/emails/deleted';
          break;
        default:
          url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/emails/inbox';
          break;
      }
    
      try {
        const userToken = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
        console.log('User Token:', userToken);
    
        if (!userToken) {
          throw new Error('User token not found in local storage');
        }
    
        const response = await axios.get(url, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
          },
        });
    
        console.log('Response:', response.data);
```

I tried in Postman but got empty array, i'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.

I have a collection name "InboxEmails" that contains inbox emails. This code was working fine when I did not added filter based on logged in user. after adding token base user authentication I am getting empty array. I want to filter and fetch emails based on current logged in user, I am already saving logged in user in local storage with token using JWT.

Comment: Did you try to print 'userEmail' and check whether it is present in the "inboxEmails" collection ?

Comment: @facebook-100001358991487 here is my schema for inboxEmails 



"{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6593875cda2dc39243b8c3ff"
  },
  "from": "example@example.com",
  "to": [
    "receiver@example.com"
  ],
  "cc": [],
  "bcc": [],
  "subject": "Test Subject",
  "message": "This is a test message",
  "receivedTime": {
    "$date": "2024-01-02T03:47:40.787Z"
  },
  "attachments": [],
  "read": true,
  "__v": 0
}"

Comment: @facebook-100001358991487 I've verified that exists